# Sorting a multiple river stream branch structure

Tags: python, sorting, tree, stream, branch

I have a list of numbered Stream segments. And each one lists the next down stream stream segment. The last stream segment of course has no down stream segment referenced.

I need to order the entire river, starting from the topmost stream and progressing down stream. At junctions I need to jump to the top of the next branch, work down stream to the junction, then continue to the next branch. There may be multiple branches (any number) joined at a junction.

For example: Sub5 flows to Sub 12
SubSINK is the LAst stream segment.
UNSORTED:

```
#####START_TOPOLOGY_BLOCK##########|###########|###########|###########|
Sub5,2454692.294,2603426.954,2456317.294,2596676.954,Sub12
Sub7,2453067.294,2598176.954,2453317.294,2596676.954,Sub12
Sub11,2462692.294,2607676.954,2461067.294,2605176.954,Sub12
Sub13,2449817.294,2601426.954,2450317.294,2593176.954,SubSINK
Sub2,2464567.294,2596801.954,2467317.294,2585676.954,Sub12
Sub12,2469942.294,2601051.954,2470817.294,2593676.954,Sub13
Sub1,2436567.294,2599676.954,2433067.294,2594676.954,Sub2
Sub3,2481067.294,2601301.954,2483067.294,2594676.954,Sub5
Sub4,2455817.294,2588801.954,2458317.294,2576426.954,Sub5
Sub6,2445067.294,2592926.954,2452817.294,2585176.954,Sub7
Sub8,2457942.294,2593551.954,2461067.294,2587426.954,Sub11
Sub9,2471442.294,2592676.954,2467817.294,2585676.954,Sub11
Sub10,2435692.294,2595176.954,2436567.294,2591176.954,Sub11
```

SORTED:

```
#####START_TOPOLOGY_BLOCK##########|###########|###########|###########|
Sub6,2445067.294,2592926.954,2452817.294,2585176.954,Sub7
Sub7,2453067.294,2598176.954,2453317.294,2596676.954,Sub12
Sub9,2471442.294,2592676.954,2467817.294,2585676.954,Sub11
Sub10,2435692.294,2595176.954,2436567.294,2591176.954,Sub11
Sub8,2457942.294,2593551.954,2461067.294,2587426.954,Sub11
Sub11,2462692.294,2607676.954,2461067.294,2605176.954,Sub12
Sub1,2436567.294,2599676.954,2433067.294,2594676.954,Sub2
Sub2,2464567.294,2596801.954,2467317.294,2585676.954,Sub12
Sub4,2455817.294,2588801.954,2458317.294,2576426.954,Sub5
Sub3,2481067.294,2601301.954,2483067.294,2594676.954,Sub5
Sub5,2454692.294,2603426.954,2456317.294,2596676.954,Sub12
Sub12,2469942.294,2601051.954,2470817.294,2593676.954,Sub13
Sub13,2449817.294,2601426.954,2450317.294,2593176.954,SubSINK
```

How can I do this efficiently ??
Thank you

Regards Rudy

2nd Example of River Topology

START_TOPOLOGY_BLOCK##########|###########|###########|###########|

Sub16,2454692.294,2603426.954,2456317.294,2596676.954,Sub17
Sub7,2453067.294,2598176.954,2453317.294,2596676.954,Sub9
Sub8,2462692.294,2607676.954,2461067.294,2605176.954,Sub9
Sub4,2449817.294,2601426.954,2450317.294,2593176.954,Sub5
Sub1,2464567.294,2596801.954,2467317.294,2585676.954,Sub2
Sub14,2469942.294,2601051.954,2470817.294,2593676.954,Sub15
Sub19,2436567.294,2599676.954,2433067.294,2594676.954,Sub20
Sub13,2481067.294,2601301.954,2483067.294,2594676.954,Sub20
Sub10,2455817.294,2588801.954,2458317.294,2576426.954,Sub11
Sub6,2445067.294,2592926.954,2452817.294,2585176.954,Sub11
Sub17,2457942.294,2593551.954,2461067.294,2587426.954,Sub18
Sub15,2471442.294,2592676.954,2467817.294,2585676.954,Sub18
Sub9,2435692.294,2595176.954,2436567.294,2591176.954,Sub10
Sub2,2475817.294,2597426.954,2474067.294,2594176.954,Sub3
Sub18,2481442.294,2593801.954,2482567.294,2587926.954,Sub19
Sub12,2484817.294,2588051.954,2483817.294,2584676.954,Sub13
Sub21,2478067.294,2592801.954,2481317.294,2587676.954,SubSINK
Sub5,2437942.294,2589801.954,2437067.294,2587176.954,Sub6
Sub3,2439442.294,2589801.954,2439317.294,2589676.954,Sub5
Sub20,2435067.294,2583801.954,2441067.294,2574426.954,Sub21
Sub11,2476317.294,2590801.954,2476067.294,2590426.954,Sub12
Sub32,2473067.294,2587301.954,2468317.294,2583426.954,Sub31
Sub33,2469817.294,2557926.954,2461317.294,2549426.954,Sub31
Sub33,2475942.294,2590551.954,2475817.294,2590426.954,Sub31
Sub34,2477692.294,2582426.954,2474567.294,2573926.954,Sub26

Comment: You need [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) here.  Have a look at the [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=Topological+sorting+Python).

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent your segments as a graph data structure. Then, familiar graph algorithms like DFS, BFS and topological sort should do the work for you, depending on what you need exactly.

If you could clarify your question with a simple example or a picture so it's clearly understood which sorting order you need, I may be able to provide a more specific direction.

Comment: Thank you ... I assume the UNSORTED FILE was your river.dat file ?? How do I call this routine from my code? I do not see an import RIVER in the test? (Sorry... Novice here !)

Comment: I have added a 2nd example data set... Could you please indicate how I would call the data file and function from my own python script

Answer (score 1):

Something simple along the following lines hopefully demonstrates how to create the proper river graph and all the methods needed to traverse on it.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y): self.xy= float(x), float(y)

def _insert(G, n, x, y, kind= 0):
    if n[kind] not in G: G[n[kind]]= [[], [], Point(x, y)]
    G[n[kind]][kind].append(n[not kind])

class River:
    def __init__(self, S= None):
        self.G= {}
        if S is not None:
            for s in S: self.insert(s)

    def insert(self, s):
        n= s[0], s[5]
        _insert(self.G, n, s[1], s[2])
        _insert(self.G, n, s[3], s[4], 1)

    def degree(self, n, kind= 1): return len(self.G[n][kind])

    def sink(self):
        for n in self.G:
            if not self.G[n][0]: return n

    def traverse(self, n0, fun, level= 0):
        for n1 in self.G[n0][1]:
            self.traverse(n1, fun, level+ 1)
            fun(n0, n1, level)
```

And a test

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import csv
    reader= csv.reader(open('river.dat', 'r'))
    reader.next()
    r= River([s for s in reader])
    def fun(n0, n1, level):
        """segment (n1, n0) has:
        level, indicating a 'hop' distance from the sink
        degree(n1, 1), in degree to segment (0 indicates a source)
        n1, id of segments start
        n0, id of segments end
        degree(n0, 0), out degree from segment (0 indicates a sink)
        """
        print '{}:({}:{} -> {}:{})'.format(
        level, r.degree(n1), n1, n0, r.degree(n0, 0))
    r.traverse(r.sink(), fun)
```

will print:

```
3:(0:Sub3 -> Sub5:1)
3:(0:Sub4 -> Sub5:1)
2:(2:Sub5 -> Sub12:1)
3:(0:Sub6 -> Sub7:1)
2:(1:Sub7 -> Sub12:1)
3:(0:Sub8 -> Sub11:1)
3:(0:Sub9 -> Sub11:1)
3:(0:Sub10 -> Sub11:1)
2:(3:Sub11 -> Sub12:1)
3:(0:Sub1 -> Sub2:1)
2:(1:Sub2 -> Sub12:1)
1:(4:Sub12 -> Sub13:1)
0:(1:Sub13 -> SubSINK:0)
```

**Edit**: With your second example. First note that you have more than 1 sink. If that's intentional, it should be quite straightforward to handle forests as well (like letting sink return all of them and then process traversing in a loop). But anyway with the first 22 rows the output is:

```
5:(0:Sub16 -> Sub17:1)
4:(1:Sub17 -> Sub18:1)
5:(0:Sub14 -> Sub15:1)
4:(1:Sub15 -> Sub18:1)
3:(2:Sub18 -> Sub19:1)
2:(1:Sub19 -> Sub20:1)
7:(0:Sub7 -> Sub9:1)
7:(0:Sub8 -> Sub9:1)
6:(2:Sub9 -> Sub10:1)
5:(1:Sub10 -> Sub11:1)
7:(0:Sub4 -> Sub5:1)
9:(0:Sub1 -> Sub2:1)
8:(1:Sub2 -> Sub3:1)
7:(1:Sub3 -> Sub5:1)
6:(2:Sub5 -> Sub6:1)
5:(1:Sub6 -> Sub11:1)
4:(2:Sub11 -> Sub12:1)
3:(1:Sub12 -> Sub13:1)
2:(1:Sub13 -> Sub20:1)
1:(2:Sub20 -> Sub21:1)
0:(1:Sub21 -> SubSINK:0)
```

**Edit 2**: My answer is more to give some ideas how to handle the river tree itself. For your particular application you most probable can find better ways to actually handle the points. But anyway you can access them now like:

```
In []: r.G['Sub8'][2].xy
Out[]: (2462692.294, 2607676.954)
In []: r.G['Sub8'][2].xy[0]
Out[]: 2462692.294
```

You may also ignore totally the `class Point` and modify `_insert` like:

```
def _insert(G, n, x, y, kind= 0):
    # if n[kind] not in G: G[n[kind]]= [[], [], Point(x, y)]
    if n[kind] not in G: G[n[kind]]= [[], [], (x, y)]
    G[n[kind]][kind].append(n[not kind])
```

Then you'll access points like:

```
In []: r.G['Sub8'][2]
Out[]: ('2462692.294', '2607676.954')
In []: r.G['Sub8'][2][0]
Out[]: '2462692.294'
```

Comment: How do I run your example ?  I looks fantastic and does it sort the following example correctly ?

Comment: When I try to run this I get an "Attribute Error 'str' object has no attribute "format" ? What have I done wrong?

Comment: @Rudy: What Python version you have? If I remember correctly `format` is supported on 2.6 and above. But anyway the `fun(.)` is just a example, try to make your own one. Thanks

Comment: Thank you eat,.... that is fantastic... However I also want access to the co-ordinate data, how can I access the X1,Y1, and X2,Y2 for the sub area to write to a file, I dont quite understand the data structure?? Could you please explain it to me?    Regards Rudy

Comment: @Rudy: Good to hear. BTW, if you found my answer useful, you may like to accept it. Thanks